# Is there a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ that satisfies $A = A^3$ and $\det(A) = 3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

> Is there a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ that satisfies $A = A^3$ and $\det(A) = 3$? Justify your answer.

Past exam paper question I can't get.

Comment: Only if $3 = det(A) = det(A^3) = det(A)^3 = 3^3 = 27$ ;)

Comment: We can take $A=0$ for $A\in M_3(\Bbb F_3)$. Then $3=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: $\mathbb F_2$ also works: Then $3=1$ and thus $A$ can be the identity matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\det(A)=3\ne0$, thus $A$ is invertible. Then from $A=A^3$ we have
$$A^{-1}A=A^{-1}A^3\Rightarrow I=A^2$$
which implies $$\det I=\det A^2=(\det A)^2$$
i.e.
$$1=(\det A)^2$$
or $\det A= \pm 1$, which contradicts our assumption that $\det A=3$.

Comment: Seems like you could reach a contradiction more directly from $\det(A)=\det(A)^3$.